# Fatal error encountered during command execution with a mySQL INSERT

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to execute a INSERT statement on a mySQL DB in C#:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=" + _dbConnection + ";" +
   "DATABASE=" + _dbName + ";" +
   "PORT=" + _dbPort + ";" +
   "UID=" + _dbUsername + ";" +
   "PASSWORD=" + _dbPassword + ";");
MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
command = new MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO plugins (pluginName, enabled) VALUES (@plugin,@enabled)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "pluginName");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enabled", false);
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

The plugin table consists of two columns: pluginName(varchar(50)) and enabled(boolean).

This fails with the error: mysql Fatal error encountered during command execution.  Any ideas on why this would fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be using `@plugin` in the query but `@name` in the parameters, although I'd expect a better error message if that was the sole problem!

Comment: If you explore the Exception's InnerException (its exceptions all the way...) you eventually find the source of the problem; in my case, a non-defined parameter (typo).

Comment: I just had this same problem, the error message is not clear at all. But thank you for helping me fix it!

Answer (score 0):

The error "*Fatal error encountered during command execution*" seems to be for general syntax errors in the CommandText line.

For example, the following just tripped me up for a while:

```
...@date,@email@first,@last...
```

Watch out for those commas!  There should be one after `@email`:

```
...@date,@email,@first,@last...
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing Parameters could also be a reason.
eg:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO login VALUES(@uname,@pwd);"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",TxtUsername.Text.ToString())
'forgot to place "@pwd"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You get fatal error which can be solved by adding

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd",TxtPassword.Text.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`(from user in _context.GetDataTable("call sp_get_user_subscribe_info(@param1, @param2)", _context.AddParameter(new dynamic[] { id }))`
```

My procedure has two parameters but I have passed only one parameter that's why this error message occurred, But this error message is so confusing.